# Conditions under which stepping into shared library should work in gdb?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

There are many questions related to specific errors why stepping into a shared library with gdb isn't working. None of them provide a systematic answer on how to confirm where the the cause is. This questions is about the ways to diagnose the setup.

### Setup example

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myshared.h"

int main(void)
{
    int a = 3;
    print_from_lib();
    return 0;
}
```

**myshared.h**

```
void print_from_lib();
```

**myshared.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_from_lib()
{
    printf("Printed from shared library\n");
}
```

Place all the files in the same directory.

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
gcc -ggdb -c -Wall -Werror -fpic myshared.c -o myshared-ggdb.o
gcc -ggdb -shared -o libmyshared-ggdb.so myshared-ggdb.o
gcc -ggdb main.c -lmyshared-ggdb -o app-ggdb
```

### Getting the error

```
$ gdb ./app-ggdb 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.12.50.20170314-0ubuntu1) 7.12.50.20170314-git
...### GDB STARTING TEXT
Reading symbols from app-ggdb...done.
(gdb) break 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x78f: file main.c, line 7.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/share-lib-example/app-ggdb 

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:7
7       print_from_lib();
(gdb) s
Printed from shared library
8       return 0;
```

gdb is not stepping inside of the function

### Necessary but not sufficient checks

#### Debug symbols in the binaries

```
$ objdump --syms libmyshared-ggdb.so | grep debug
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_aranges 0000000000000000              .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_info    0000000000000000              .debug_info
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_abbrev  0000000000000000              .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_line    0000000000000000              .debug_line
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_str     0000000000000000              .debug_str
```

#### Symbols recognized by gdb

```
$ gdb ./app-ggdb
...### GDB STARTING TEXT
Reading symbols from app-ggdb...done.
(gdb) break 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x78f: file main.c, line 7.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/share-lib-example/app-ggdb 

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:7
7       print_from_lib();
(gdb)(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7dd7aa0  0x00007ffff7df55c0  Yes         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007ffff7bd5580  0x00007ffff7bd5693  Yes         /home/user/share-lib-example/libmyshared-ggdb.so
0x00007ffff782d9c0  0x00007ffff797ed43  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

#### Confirm .gdbinit isn't the cause

`~/.gdbinit` contains commands automatically executed upon starting gdb. [ref.](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbinit-man.html)

Running gdb with the `-nx` flags can exclude `.gdbinit` as the source of the problem.

## Question

Am looking for suggestions to complete the list of `Necessary but not sufficient checks`.

**Current issue [Update from  Mark Plotnick]**

This step bug is reproducible on Ubuntu 17.04 amd64 with both a 64- and 32-bit executable and library.

The bug isn't reproducible on Ubuntu 17.04 i386. (gcc 6.3.0-12ubuntu2, gdb 7.12.50 and 8.0, no .gdbinit.).

Possibly relevant: gcc on 17.04 amd64 has been built (by Canonical) to generate pie executables by default.

**Question**

Can flags with which gcc was build with interfere with debugging? How can you identify if your gcc is the cause?

Comment: From whoever cast a close, would appreciate a pointer on what part isn't clear.

Comment: I'm just speculating, but *"Am looking for suggestions to complete the list of Necessary but not sufficient checks"* is not a real good question in my opinion. The grammar sounds like ESL; and "suggestions to complete the list" leaves a lot to be desired. I parse *"Necessary but not sufficient checks"* as, steps which you can perform that don't accomplish your goal. Its kind of a bogus question.

Comment: @jww It is a path to provoke answers of `most useful things to try first if your debugging isn't working` before posting yet another  `gdb and shared lib` type of question. Once a list of methods have been found that point to the solution, I will rephrase the question. Having just asked `Ways to debug gdb shared library` without an example looked like a way to get the question closed. :)

Comment: GDB 7.11 can't reproduce your problem. In GDB, use `show env LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to ensure the library path is correct or you can use `set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` to set it.

Comment: @haolee `show env LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is correct. Just tried also with gdb 8.0 same thing, `s` not stepping into `print_from_lib()`. Can you please explain what happened in your case? Perhaps as an answer with steps?

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer and Haolee - I beleve location has something to do with being able to step into shared objects. I seem to recall Debian and/or Fedora will not step into system shared objects by default, and you have to jump through hoops to do it. If I recall "system shared objects" are those located in `/lib`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc. It regularly wastes my time for libraries I install into `/usr/local/lib`. I usually give up in frustration, and re-run the experiment with everything built in my home directory. In my home directory, I can step into shared objects.

Comment: FWIW, this step bug is reproducible on Ubuntu 17.04 amd64 (which I believe is the same as what OP is running) with both a 64- and 32-bit executable and library, but the bug isn't reproducible on Ubuntu 17.04 i386. (gcc 6.3.0-12ubuntu2, gdb 7.12.50 and 8.0, no .gdbinit.) Possibly relevant: gcc on 17.04 amd64 has been built (by Canonical) to generate pie executables by default.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is self-imposed: don't do this: `set step-mode on`, and `step` will work as you expect.

From the GDB [manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#Continuing-and-Stepping):

```
set step-mode
set step-mode on
The set step-mode on command causes the step command to stop at the first
instruction of a function which contains no debug line information
rather than stepping over it.

This is useful in cases where you may be interested in inspecting the machine
instructions of a function which has no symbolic info and do not want
GDB to automatically skip over this function.
```

You are interested in the *opposite* of the above -- you want to step *into* the `print_from_lib` function and avoid stopping inside the PLT jump stub and the dynamic loader's symbol resolution function.

Comment: Thanks, updated based on your suggestion but it still isn't stepping into the library function.
Is it ok to use `objdump --syms libmyshared-ggdb.so | grep debug` for checking the existence  of debug symbols? There was one answer you gave where you suggested `readelf -d libmyshared-ggdb.so | grep DEBUG` which returns empty in this example.

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer I can't reproduce your observed behavior using  GDB 7.9, 8.0.50.20170429-git, and 8.0.50.20170725-git. Are you *sure* you don't have another `set step-mode` in your `~/.gdbinit`? Maybe try running with `gdb -nx app-ggdb` to be sure?

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately wasn't the cause. Great suggestion though, added it to the potential list of checks. After your suggestion I removed `set step-mode on` and it's just stepping over `print_from_lib();` now.

Answer (score 6):

GDB 7.11 can't reproduce this problem.
This is my steps. I hope this will help you:

```
1.gcc -ggdb -c -Wall -Werror -fpic myshared.c -o myshared-ggdb.o
2.gcc -ggdb -shared -o libmyshared-ggdb.so myshared-ggdb.o
3.gcc -ggdb main.c -lmyshared-ggdb -o app-ggdb -L.
4.gdb ./app-ggdb
```

In GDB,

```
(gdb) set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
(gdb) b main.c:7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4006a5: file main.c, line 7.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/haolee/tmp/app-ggdb 

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:7
7       print_from_lib();
(gdb) s
print_from_lib () at myshared.c:5
5       printf("Printed from shared library\n");
(gdb)
```

I step into the function `print_from_lib` successfully.

Comment: Just tried gdb 7.11, 7.12., 8. on two different machines and couldn't step in. Strange. What version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer The gcc version is `6.3.1 20161221`

Comment: Copy `libmyshared-ggdb.so` into `/usr/local/lib`. You likely won't be able to step it.

Answer (score 4):

Some more tests you can do on built shared library:

1. `file libmyshared-ggdb.so` should report that library has debug info and not stripped.
2. `nm libmyshared-ggdb.so | grep print_from_lib` should find the symbol for `print_from_lib` function.

If all above tests passed try to load the library directly in gdb and find the function:

```
gdb libmyshared-ggdb.so
(gdb) info functions print_from_lib
```

Function `print_from_lib` name should be printed. If not, something is wrong with gdb or gcc.

Comment: Copy `libmyshared-ggdb.so` into `/usr/local/lib`. You likely won't be able to step it.